# helping in writing or correcting this part of a sentence

Tags: phrase-usage

> I am tired of or fed up with those who their nasty tempers are disgusting

Would you please show me if the writing sound correct?

nasty tempers: a series characters or habits that are considered very outrageous, or temperamental and have a tendency to reply or react in an unpredictable manner-- often disapproving or unpleasant or unkind.

Some more details: I would like to say:

1. I am fed up with those people
2. which people? those who make us disgusting through or by their nasty tempers or characters

Comment: I think you haven't quite got the right word with ***tempers*** (your own ***habits*** is much better). More natural phrasing for what I assume you mean would be *I'm fed up with people who have disgusting habits*, or even more likely perhaps *I'm sick of other people's disgusting habits* (since it's not the people themselves, it's what they *do* that irritates you).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree about "habits".  The asker is characterizing the trait as habitual, but is not criticizing a habit; the asker is criticizing the trait of having a temper, and is using the term correctly.

Comment: @Codeswitcher: I did say *what I **assume** OP means*. I think I commented, and the question was edited, within the first few minutes o posting, since so far as I recall OP hadn't included the specific word ***temperamental*** in the original text. My primary point (which I *still* think) is that OP is conflating ***temper*** (usually, an *angry outburst*) with [***temperament***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/temperament) *- the manner of thinking, behaving, or reacting characteristic of a specific person*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am fed up with those people

This part is perfect.

> which people? those who make us disgusting through or by their nasty tempers or characters

You're misusing **disgusting**.  **Disgusting** is the property of something that provokes the feeling of disgust in others.  Those others who have the feeling of disgust provoked in them are **disgusted**, so that's the word you want to use in this construction.

This gives us:

> I am fed up with those people who make us disgusted through their nasty tempers or characters.

That's a perfectly fine sentence, if a little grammatically awkward.

Please note that one person doesn't have multiple **characters** in the sense you're using it, except over time.  **Character** is a summative description of a person over all.  So generally, unless we're discussing a person whose character changes (e.g. "He showed two different characters depending on whether he was at home or out with his friends"), a person has **a** character, and multiple people can then be described between them as having **characters**.

Back to your question:

> I am tired of or fed up with those who their nasty tempers are disgusting

This has one problem: **who their**.  **Who** is a pronoun here, and instead of following it with a second pronoun to express the possessive, just make it possessive:

> I am tired of or fed up with those whose nasty tempers are disgusting

Other sentences which get at similar sentiments:

> I am disgusted by nasty tempers
>
> I am disgusted by those with nasty tempers
>
> I am fed up with, tired of, and disgusted by those with nasty tempers.
>
> Nasty tempers disgust me, and I'm fed up by those who have them.
>
> I am fed up with and tired of those people with nasty, disgusting tempers.
>
> I am fed up with and tired of those disgusting people with nasty tempers.
>
> I am fed up with and tired of those disgusting people who have nasty tempers
>
> I am fed up with and tired of those disgusting people and their nasty tempers.

Comment: I think _fed up_ carries both the notion of "tired of" and "disgusted by". Therefore, my suggestion would be the rather simple: *I am fed up with people who have nasty tempers.*

Answer (score 0):

Your quote is not technically a run-on sentence, but it reads like one. A run-on sentence is one in which two or more independent clauses are joined without appropriate punctuation or conjunction. Split the quote into two sentences. Otherwise, the statement sounds as if you're okay with people whose nasty tempers are **not** disgusting.

I am tired of nasty-tempered people. Their nasty tempers are disgusting.

Note: Someone help me with the punctuation. Some grammarians claim that hyphenated adjectives are archaic. Should nasty tempered be two words?

Comment: I think the hyphen is fine in this case. Hyphens tend to drop when the phrase starts to become commonplace.